# How do I create this type of Task List, with columns "Status" and "Description" instead of "Task Status" and "Body"?

Tags: tasks

I have 2 site collections, A and B.

In site collection A, when I create a new Task List, the columns are (I will call it "Type A"):

- % Complete
- Assigned To
- **Body** (this one is different)
- Due Date
- Predecessors
- Priority
- Start Date
- Task Group
- **Task Status** (this one is different)
- Title
- Workflow Name
- Created By
- Modified By

In Site Collection B, the newly created Task List will have columns like this  (I will call it "Type B"):

- % Complete
- Assigned To
- **Description** (this one is different)
- Due Date
- Predecessors
- Priority
- Start Date
- **Status** (this one is different)
- Task Group
- Title
- Workflow Name
- Created By
- Modified By

It seems like these are two types of Task List. I use the same method to create the new task list:

**Site Actions - More Options - (Filter by List) then select "Tasks"**

There are some existing Type B Task List in Site Collection A, but when I create new ones, they are always Type A. How can I create Type B Task List in Site Collection A?

I hope this is not too confusing...

Comment: Go to list settings of both lists and look at what content types they are using. Try to match content types in use and you are done!

Comment: Hi Prashant, Thanks for your reply. I can see they are different content types, but how do I match content types in use?

Comment: You can click on add existing content type and add the missing content type. You can click on content type and remove it if you dont want it

Comment: The content types on both sites are called "Task" and they all inherit from the "Task" content type (ctype=0x0108). So I can't add the "missing" content type...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Task content-Type that inherits from Task, and then create a list template that specifically uses your content-type.

It may be a little tricky but check On-Line documentation for the correct mark-up for Lists and Content-Type definition.

You might have to deploy them using a solution.

Hope it helps.

The custom content type creation can be seen [here](http://jsuhail.blogspot.com/2014/06/create-custom-outcome-options-in.html).

Comment: Thanks TheBigCheese, all my Task List Content Type inherit from Task Content Type (0x0108). They just worked differently...

Comment: It's the same. You can also hide or remove the unwanted fields.

If you wish to keep the same workflows running on top of them, I think you can set only the display name.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible the Task content type in site collection A got modified from its original definition. I would just modify the Task content type in site collection A (at the site collection level), change the field display names to Description and Status, and you should be all set with future Task lists in site collection A. For existing task lists with the incorrect column names, I would update them separately

If you want a custom Task content type, and you want it to be available in all site collections, I would actually recommend utilizing content type syndication, which is an OOB feature in SharePoint, rather than a custom solution as was suggested in another answer. Read more about that [here](https://collab365.community/understanding-content-type-hub-cth-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to each library settings and open these columns, in url check Internal Name of these columns, maybe it will be the same, but only title is different, so you can rename columns to what you want.

If it is not the same, probably you used different web templates when creating.